# How to correctly retrieve data from firestore in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to retrieve some data from a firestore database in Angular 7, in which I have some data. I've done this before, but now, for some reason, I keep getting a "TypeError: x is not a Function" error in one of the objects I retrieve from the DB.

I've tried the "get" method from AngularFirestore to retrieve a document, which I know the ID from previous operations.

This is what I've done so far to retrieve the object:

```js
loadInitial(params) {
    this.afs.doc(`path/to/my/document`)
      .get()
      .subscribe(
        (elem: DocumentSnapshot<TravRow>) => {
          this.editTravel = elem.data();
          this.updateForm();
          this.loading = false;
        }
      );
  }
```

This seems to work, but when I execute this event:

```js
onDateChange(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Moment>) {
    console.log(event.value.format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
    this.editTravel.travDates = new TravDates();
    this.editTravel.travDates.startDate = event.value.toDate();
    this.editTravel.travDates.endDate = event.value.toDate();
    this.editTravel.travDates.endDate.setDate(
      this.editTravel.travDates.endDate.getDate() + 
      (this.editTravel.getTravDays() - 1)
    );
  }
```

It says that "this.editTravel.getTravDays()" is not a function. I have even initialized the object and seems that it does not work.

It should be a function because I have it already defined, but it seems that, when it retrieves the object from the database, it doesn't link with the JavaScript object.

Comment: `this.editTravel = new TravRow();
          this.editTravel = elem.data();` looks like nonsense. It might not be but if it is correct then something very obscure is going on.

Comment: I've tried to work with and without `this.editTravel = new TravRow();`, but it seems that nothing happens...

Comment: But you're overwriting the value of editRow immediately